# How to calculate group means for a mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, mean, proportion

I want to know what is the formula used to calculate group means (for example, mean for the Treatment group and mean for the Control group; or means for the groups A and B) in the context of a mixed model.

I know that for the proportions I can calculate them this way:

```
p_A = 1/(1+exp⁡(-(intercept+fixedEffectForTratfB×0)))=1/(1+exp⁡(-intercept))

p_B=  1/(1+exp⁡(-(intercept+fixedEffectForTratfB×1)))=1/(1+exp⁡(-(intercept+fixedEffectForTratfB)))
```

where the example model is:

```
outcome_ij = intercept +id_i + fixedEffectForTratfB × tratfB + e_ij
```

And the code in R for the proportions is:

```
pA <- as.numeric((1)/(1+exp(-model$coefficients$fixed[1])))

pB <- as.numeric((1)/(1+exp(-model$coefficients$fixed[1]-model$coefficients$fixed[2])))

model <- glmmPQL(outcome~tratf,random=list(~1|id) ,data ,niter=50, family=binomial)
```